# layout function doesn't change View dimension.

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a view that slides up from the bottom of the screen. I tried setting the initial position of the view (which should be offscreen) in xml, but instead of placing the imageview where I specified, it truncated it. My second thought was to set the position of the view programatically inside the onWindowFocusChanged method. Here's my code

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
    slide_dock.layout(slide_dock.getLeft(), phone_height - 70, slide_dock.getRight(), phone_height + 230);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this only works SOME of the time. I've been debugging it, and I believe the issue is that the layout values of slide_dock get altered after my onWindowFocusChanged function completes, I'm just not sure where. Can anyone here help me out? Or link me to somewhere that explains the layout process in-depth? I've been searching around to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Animation framework?  Use a RelativeLayout and align your child view to the bottom of the parent.  Then use the following animation, maybe showing and hiding your view appropriately with `View.setVisibility(int)`

```
View myView = View(this);

TranslateAnimation slideUp = new TranslateAnimation(myView.getHeight(), 0, 0, 0);
slideUp.setDuration(250);    // millis
slideUp.setFillAfter(true);  // Required for animation to "stick" when done
myView.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

You might have to play with the TranslateAnimation constructor parameters to get it to work right (this is from the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks for the response ptc. I had actually used this solution prior to me writing my post, but it didn't produce results that were "polished enough" so to speak. I actually figured out what was causing the problem. I'm posting it below in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the cause for the issue above, and I'm posting it here in case anyone ever runs into the same problem.

The reason why the ImageView was resizing was because in ImageView's onMeasure function, it resizes itself if it doesn't think that it will fit onto the screen. You can view the ImageView source here and see how it works: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java&d=3

To work around this, I created a custom view that extended ImageView and overrode the onMeasure method. In my new onMeasure method, I simply called setDimension to give my new view the dimensions that I wanted it to have, this effectively stopped the view from resizing as it was doing earlier

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), 300);

}
```